# XCode – XCode 4.2 beta ARC will not compile

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to build a simple OS X Command Line application in XCode 4.2 beta (Build 4D58). But I'm getting an error when I try to compile it saying:

> /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:57:22: error: 'CFMakeCollectable' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode [3]
>        return (cf ? (id)CFMakeCollectable(cf) : nil);

And

> /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:173:13: error: use of undeclared identifier '__bridge_retain' [3]
>        return (__bridge_retain CFTypeRef)X;

I guess this has something to do with ARC but I'm not sure what to do have my application compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 4.2 beta is under NDA. You'd better to search "NSZone.h NSObject.h" for all periods in the developer forum. You will find the exact same question as yours.